# Instantiate UIViewController programmatically without nib

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I want to create a `UIViewController` programmatically without the use of a nib or a storyboard.

I thought it would be enough to implement the `UIViewController` as:

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Add some setup code here, without it it should just be blank
    }
}
```

instantiate it with  `let vc = TestViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)` or just `TestViewController()`

and then just push it:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

But it shows the `navigationController` (upper bar) with a transparent View (the `UIWindow` behind is being shown, I have a multi-window setup)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the docs:

> If the view controller does not have an associated nib file, this method creates a plain UIView object instead.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/view

If you do not provide a nib file when instantiating the view controller, UIViewController calls it's `loadView()` method which creates a plain UIView object and assigns it to its view property.

The reason why you are seeing a transparent view is because the UIView object has no background color. To verify this, you can set the background color of the view controller's view property right before you push it on your navigation stack.

```
let viewController = TestViewController()
viewController.view.backgroundColor = .blueColor()
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: It seems I was using `viewDidLoad` instead of `loadView`. That was my problem.

Comment: Exactly. Override `loadView` method if you need to provide a custom UIView implementation to your view controller.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to setup your views in the `loadView` method of `UIViewController` and assign your root view to the `view` property.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView for additional details.

Comment: Each UIViewController should have a top level view that it owns which contains all the other views. A reference to this view is stored in the UIViewController's view property. More details on this property can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/view

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
 let vc = UIViewController()

    let view1 = UIView()

    view1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)

    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    vc.view = view1


    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

hope this will help :)

Comment: This made no difference. Same behaviour.

Comment: Set background color to view. so you got idea that it is working