# how can i get NibName of viewcontroller while not using storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode8, initwithnibname

I'm trying to implement a page menu  in my app using the pod from [this pre-built page menu pod from github](https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu)

In the instructions, it says:

```
var controller : UIViewController = UIViewController(nibName:"controllerNibName", bundle: nil)
controller.title = "SAMPLE TITLE"
controllerArray.append(controller)
```

things are all set up but i need only "controllerNibName". I am not using storyboard. And haven't made any xib file yet  with viewController. so how can i get the NibName of viewController.

Comment: Its a xib file name, where you have done all the UI related to that UIViewController

Comment: is that necessary to create a xib file with viewController @subramaniam

Comment: Not necessary, if you are not creating the UI by using xib then not required

Comment: Check my answer. `let pageOne = PageOne()` even you have xib it will pick, if not then it will create new one which is not referred to any xib

Comment: Without xib how will you create UI?

Comment: actually I'm new to programming and swift both. i always used to create UI in viewDidLoad programmatically. @subramanian

Answer (score 3):

`controllerNibName` string is a file name of your `XIB`. Where you have done all the UI which is related with your `UIViewController`.

If your `viewController` class name and `xib` file names are same then you can directly allocate the `UIViewController`. It will pick the xib automatically.

Assume `UIViewController` name is `PageOne` & xib name also should be `PageOne.xib`

```
let pageOne = PageOne()
```

if your xib name is different from your view controller name

For Example : `Page1.xib`

```
let pageOne = PageOne(nibName:"Page1", bundle: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice way to get a name of nib (if nib name is equal to controller name i.e. MyViewController.xib and MyViewController):

```
let controllerName = String(describing: MyViewController.self)
var controller : MyViewController = MyViewController(nibName:controllerName, bundle: nil)
```

Comment: thanks @eridana it  works pretty well. but can you give me a way to do it without creating xib files just because i have made all UI programmatically.

Comment: @PrateekRegar I've found this question, maybe this is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37526411/2908082